# Scoping problem when assigning functions in a loop

Tags: r, scoping

I would like to create a bunch of functions with a particular structure in the variable name as a crude workaround for what should be one function with multiple arguments (this I cannot do directly). Let's consider the following analogous example:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:2){
    temp_fun <- function(x){
      (x+i)^j
      }
    assign(paste0("fun", paste0("_plus_", i, "_pow_", j)), temp_fun)
  }
}
```

This loop creates 6 functions that have `x` as dependent variable only

```
fun_plus_1_pow_1
fun_plus_1_pow_2
fun_plus_2_pow_1
fun_plus_2_pow_2
fun_plus_3_pow_1
fun_plus_3_pow_2
```

For instance `fun_plus_2_pow_1(2)` should return `(2+2)^1 = 4`, however it returns `25`. I know what happens here, the values for `i` and `j` get updated while the loop is running and eventually `i=3` and `j=2`are taken resulting in `(2+3)^2 = 25`.

But how can I make them local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option. I also changed that `assign` stuff (creating a bunch of systematically named objects in the global environment is a clear sign to use a list instead).

```
funs <- matrix(list(), 3, 2, dimnames = list(paste0("plus", 1:3), 
                                             paste0("pow", 1:2)))

for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:2){
    create_fun <- function(i, j){
      #force evaluation so that the values are stored in the closure
      force(i); force(j) 
      function(x) (x+i)^j
    }
    funs[i, j][[1]] <- create_fun(i, j)
  }
}

funs["plus2", "pow1"][[1]](2)
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this?  Would it be sufficient to just define one function `fun(x, i, j)` and then use partial application:

```
library(pryr)
fun <- function(x, i, j) (x + i)^j

partial(fun, i = 2, j = 1)(2) 
## [1] 4

# an example of passing partial(...) as a function to another function, i.e. to sapply
sapply(1:10, partial(fun, i = 2, j = 1))
## [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Note that `partial(fun, i = i, j = j)` for particular values of `i` and `j` is a function of `x` alone.